# PHP Post variable not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, post

I am sending data to a PHP script using an android app. The following is the PHP script.

telejoke.php:

```
<?php
  include 'JokeValidation.php';
  include 'DBConnect.php';

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $joke = $_POST['joke'];
  $dbname = 'Telejoke';
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

  if (validate()){
    $query = "INSERT INTO jokes (username, joke) VALUES ('$username','$joke')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
  }
  mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

jokevalidation.php:

```
<?php
  include 'DBConnect.php';
  $dbname = 'telejoke';
  mysql_select_db($dbname);
  function validate(){
    if ($joke == null) return false;
    else if($username == null) return false;
   return true;
  }
?>
```

For some reason, the PHP script will put the data into the database when I take out `if ($joke == null) return false;` and `else if($username == null) return false;`. But when I put these statements into the PHP code, it seems that validate returns false. This is weird because $username and $joke will go to my database when I take out these statements meaning they cannot be null!.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: and from where to you guess is your validate method getting the vars ?

Comment: thought variables were document scope. :P

Comment: Tip: use include_once on your DBConnect.php file, so you don't get multiple connections created... and from the looks of it jokevalidation.php doesn't even need a database connection at all (unless you gave us just a snippet).

Comment: No it doesn't need the connection. And I will be sure to remove the other include. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your validate function needs to have access to the $joke and $username objects.

```
function validate($joke, $validate) {
    if ($joke == null)
        return false;
    else if ($username == null)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

You can also get access to these variables by using the following inside your validate method:

```
global $joke, $username
```

However, it is better to declare what you're validating rather than relying on those variables being declared and set elsewhere in your code. Using global might fail silently for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Variables have *function scope*. The variables `$joke` and `$username` do not exist inside the function, because you have neither declared nor passed them into the function. Use function parameters:

```
function validate($joke, $username) {
   ...
}

if (validate($joke, $username)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: oh. I thought they had document scope. Thx for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

`function validate($joke,$username)`

also, filter those `postvars` before inserting them into your db.